# MySQL: Re-doing my structures. How can I move my existing data?

Tags: mysql

I decided to redo my MySQL table structure. How can I move the data into the new tables from old tables. What would be the best way to do it? Currently, I am using phpmyadmin. Is there a way to pipe like in Unix i.e. `SELECT * FROM table | UPDATE` ?

Answer (score 2):

`INSERT...SELECT` is your best bet. Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html

eg:

```
INSERT INTO destinationTable (col1, col2, col3) 
SELECT oldcol1, oldcol2, oldcol3 
FROM sourceTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move data into the new tables by executing

```
INSERT newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable
```

if the new tables aren't created yet:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable
SELECT * FROM oldtable
```

Comment: How does it know which columns that data goes into?

Comment: @Doug i was assuming the table definitions are the same, if not, look at Will's answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to, simply do something like

```
create table new_table like old_table;
insert into new_table select * from old_table;
```

If the structure is different:

```
create table new_table ...; <-- whatever definition

insert into new_table 
select 
  (FUNCTION_CALL to change column value)
from old_table;
```

example

```
insert into new_table 
select 
  concat(title, ' by ', author) as title ...
from old_table;
```